# Your code send nothing back test error python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, testing

I actually pass a test and I have here to calculate the lowest total carbon footprint of all possible routes.
I know there is multiple way to do this but I tried something like this:

```
compositionAller = []
compositionRetour = []
for element in range(int(lines[0])):
    date = lines[element + 1].split(" ")[0]
    heure, minutes, secondes = map(int, date.split(":"))
    ville = lines[element + 1].split(" ")[1]
    emmission = int(lines[element + 1].split(" ")[2])
    if ville == "Paris-Lyon":
        compositionAller.append([heure, minutes, secondes, ville, emmission])
    else:
        compositionRetour.append([heure, minutes, secondes, ville, emmission])

MeilleurTrajet = None
for aller in compositionAller:
    for retour in compositionRetour:
        if aller[0] == retour[0] and aller[1] < retour[1]or aller[0] < retour[0] or aller[0] == retour[0] and aller[1] == retour[1] and aller[2] <= retour[2] :
            if not MeilleurTrajet or MeilleurTrajet > aller[-1] + retour[-1]:
                MeilleurTrajet = aller[-1] + retour[-1]

print(MeilleurTrajet)
```

But arrived at test case 7 they always said there is an error your code send nothing back and I don't have access to the list to try it by my side.
So if someone can help me to know where is the error.
Here is an example of the table that we can get:

```
[
"500",
"22:24:09 Paris-Lyon 487",
"09:39:29 Paris-Lyon 2",
"10:20:32 Lyon-Paris 3",
]
```

I tried to change the condition to check hours minutes and secondes but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote

```
for aller in compositionAller:
    for retour in compositionRetour:
        if aller[0] == retour[0] and aller[1] < retour[1] or aller[0] < retour[0] or aller[0] == retour[0] and aller[1] == retour[1] and aller[2] <= retour[2] :
            if not MeilleurTrajet or MeilleurTrajet > aller[-1] + retour[-1]:
```

This seems very inconvenient.
Humans will read / debug this code; humans are good at story telling.
Much better to use words ("seconde") than numbers (`[0]`).

Also, I would prefer an identifier of `meilleurEmmission`
for consistency with code above, to clarify it
has CO2 units, but that's a minor point.
(And [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) asks for `meilleur_emmission`, whatever.)

The inconvenience starts here:

```
        compositionAller.append([heure, minutes, secondes, ville, emmission])
```

Tack on an import.

```
import datetime as dt
```

We *know* we're going to have to compare H,M,S against H,M,S.
Why make it painful, why do it piecemeal?
Here's a pair of better ways to represent same thing:

1. Keep H,M,S, but *as a tuple*: `.append([(heure, minutes, secondes), ville, emmission])`
2. Abandon H,M, preferring SI units: `.append([dt.timeinterval(hours=heure, minutes=minutes, seconds=secondes), ville, emmission])`

If you prefer integers, then `dt.timeinterval(...).total_seconds()` would
give you e.g. 300 seconds for a five-minute journey.

Ok, suddenly that giant `if` expression has
become more manageable, it is very easy to
ask which journey has shorter duration.

---

You say your code doesn't generalize over all test cases.

Here is one more expression in the original code
that worries me:

```
    if ville == "Paris-Lyon":
```

That seems very hard-coded, very brittle.

I don't know what the original problem statement is,
and what valid city names might be.

But I worry that you need

```
    start, end = ville.split("-")
```

and that you may need some fancier logic,
perhaps with a `dict` lookup,
to keep track of outbound and inbound routes
for multiple cities which aren't necessarily
Paris or Lyon.
Also, if we must handle a Paris -> Auxerre
followed by Auxerre -> Lyon compound route,
then a much more complex approach to graph
traversal will be needed.

Bonne chance!

Comment: Thanks you for your help I cleared that but I have the same issue I think my code is too slow or make too much loop because I have the error "Maximum execution time has been reached" always for the test case 7 and "your code send nothing back".

Comment: You have quadratic nested loops, giving O(N^2) running time. I bet example 7 is deliberately long to stress that, to distinguish between such an algorithm and O(N log N) algorithm. Suppose composition{Aller,Retour} were sorted. Could you inspect fewer elements, and exit early? That is, could you do better than quadratic time?